# How do I handle a dynamic number of columns in CSS grid when I need different widths?

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to create a CSS grid that looks like this:

```
| 50 pixels | auto | 100 pixels | 100 pixels | 100 pixels | 100 pixels | 50 pixels | 50 pixels
```

Screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9CGY.jpg

Right now I am defining the columns width using grid-template-columns

But I can't figure out how to make the four columns of a 100 pixels (the red ones in the screenshot) dynamically. There could be just one column here, two, three or four. If there are fewer than four columns, then the column with "auto" width should take up the extra space.

Comment: I don't think css-grid can do this layout. Flexbox is probably a better option here: https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/xJyKMK ... Is that the result you were interested in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 1fr auto 50px 50px
}

.subgrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 100px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>50px</div>
    <div>auto</div>
    <div class='subgrid'>
      <div>100px</div>
      <div>100px</div>
      <div>100px</div>
    </div>
    <div>50px</div>
    <div>50px</div>
  </div>
```

You can see the snippet here:

https://jsbin.com/zafopivine/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 2):

Try this flex based solution

```css
        .container{
            display: flex;
            height: 150px;
            width: 100%;
            
        }
        .child-100, .child-50, .child-auto{
            flex-grow: 1;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
        .child-100{
            flex: 0 0 100px;
        }
        .child-50{
            flex: 0 0 50px;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="container" >
        <div class="child-50">child-50</div>
        <div class="child-auto">child-auto</div>
        <div class="child-100">child-100</div>
        <div class="child-100">child-100</div>
        <div class="child-100">child-100</div>
        <div class="child-100">child-100</div>
        <div class="child-50">child-50</div>
        <div class="child-50">child-50</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the flex version! I actually ended up using it, but since question was about the CSS grid I thought @Armin's answer was the most correct.